# Why doesn't pyserial write on Linux?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I've coded a simple script for Windows that works fine and I have adapted it to Linux (Ubuntu). The problem is that it doesn't read the byte sent.

I tried all the different serial ports available according to the Arduino IDE but the problem persists.I also used \n and \r without success and different encodings.

Code working on win10:

```py
import serial
import time
import keyboard
arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=0)

while True:
  arduino.write('a'.encode())    
  time.sleep(0.1)
  print(arduino.readline())
```

Code not working on Ubuntu:

```
import serial, time
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMC0', 9600, timeout = 0)
while True:
  arduino.write('a'.encode())    
  time.sleep(0.1)
  print(arduino.readline())
```

So the first script prints continuously `a\r\n`, the second doesn't. Simply shows `b''` continuously. So I think it doesn't simply write the letter.

Comment: You are missing the baudrate argument on your Ubuntu code.

Comment: @hcheung I'm sorry. I forgot it when typing the question. The problem still exists.

Comment: Instead of `realine()` use `read()` and check whether you get anything printed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. No idea what exactly was thr issue but worked sending capital letter.